# Product recovery from the current cart in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, product, cart, quote

I work on prestashop 1.7 and I would like to recover (thanks to $cart->getproduct() and context) the contents of the current cart to offer a quote to customers, however, I do not think I have the level to do it. I would like to retrieve the name of the product and its image. I had thought of doing a foreach loop. (I work in php file not tpl) Thank you in advance !

```
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.inc.php');
    $context = new Context();
    $cart = new Cart($context);
    $cartProducts = $cart->getProducts();
    print_r($cartProducts);
    var_dump($cartProducts);
```

This code part reads: 'Array ()' 
and the var_dump : array (size=0)
                     empty

Comment: Hi there, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The code is wrong, this code should works:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.inc.php');
$cart = new Cart(Context::getContext()->cart->id);
$cartProducts = $cart->getProducts();
print_r($cartProducts);
var_dump($cartProducts);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but the result is the same. :)

Comment: If result is the same, then there is not an active cart created in that session

Comment: Thanks again ! my website serves me to generate quotes, so I made a redirection to a file .php (form) in the cart.tpl file, would this be the problem and do you have a solution?

Comment: If you want to get a specific cart information, which is NOT in the context, you need change "`Context::getContext()->cart->id`" for the cart ID you need. The "`Context::getContext()->cart->id`" will get the id cart existing in the cookie of the browser where is executing the file. In other words, it's NOT valid if you need get it from an external request.